# SQL query to select single record when record may exist in another colum

Tags: sql

i just need help putting together a query. Below is an example of what I would like to achieve:

**Table name: Current_Orders_tbl**

[image]

**Indented output query**

[image]

We can get an order without a transaction_id, or an order that has an order_id that is the same as a transaction_id in the table.

When I query the table, I would like to only see:

- The order_id that contains a transaction_id that matches an already used order_id.
- The null transaction_id if that order_id hasn't been used before

Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COALESCE(table2.order_id, table1.order_Id) AS order_id, 
    table1.order_name, 
    COALESCE(table2.transaction_id, table1.transaction_id) AS transaction_id
FROM current_orders_tbl AS table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Current_orders_tbl AS table2 ON table1.order_id = table2.transaction_iD
WHERE 
    (table1.transaction_id IS NULL and table2.order_id IS NULL) OR
    Table2.order_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the assistance. I have tried incorporating this however, as a result I still get the id appearing twice. 1. Under the orders_id 2. Under the transaction_id

Comment: Updated my solution a bit. Had my join criteria backwards and needed to manage the data going into the final grid differently.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here.

The partition will be done by `order_name` and we will sort by `transaction_id`:

```
WITH sub AS
(SELECT order_id, order_name, transaction_id, 
ROW_NUMBER() 
  OVER (PARTITION BY order_name ORDER BY transaction_id DESC) AS rowNr
FROM Current_Orders_tbl)
SELECT order_id, order_name, transaction_id
FROM sub
WHERE rowNr = 1;
```

This will - according to your sample - fetch only that row per order_name having the highest transaction_id.

Try out [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q1t5Ez_5)

Sidenote: If the result of that query should be sorted, I think adding `ORDER BY order_id, order_name` would be best here.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `exists` and correlated subquery as the following:

```
select order_id, order_name, transaction_id 
from table_name T
where 
  ( /* for the 1st requirement: The order_id that contains a transaction_id that matches an already used order_id.*/
    transaction_id is not null and 
    exists(select 1 from table_name D where D.order_id = T.transaction_id)
  )
or
 ( /* for the 2nd requirement: The null transaction_id if that order_id hasn't been used before. */
   transaction_id is null and 
   not exists(select 1 from table_name D where D.transaction_id = T.order_id)
 )
```

[See demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/UyshHZE7)